# What is the difference between sum of divisors that are perfect powers and sum of powerful divisors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

[A091051](https://oeis.org/A091051) :-  Sum of divisors of n that are perfect powers.

[A183097](https://oeis.org/A183097) :- Sum of powerful divisors d (including 1) of n.

At a(72) ,one equals 58 and the other equals 130.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) and a [powerful number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number)?

Comment: A powerful number is just a number such that, for every prime $p$ which divides it, so does $p^2$.  It need not be a perfect power.

Comment: To be precise:  $72=2^3\times 3^2$ is the smallest powerful number which is not a perfect power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd sequence seems to be the sum of all divisors which happen to be [powerful numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number)

The 1st sequence is clear, I guess. Sum of all divisors which are [perfect powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power).